# How to lowercase string with special characters?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array in PHP:

```
$weekdays = array(
"mandag" => 1,
"tirsdag" => 2,
"onsdag" => 3,
"torsdag" => 4,
"fredag" => 5,
"lørdag" => 6,
"søndag" => 7);
```

The function gets the day with random formats like all uppercase or one letter uppercase, I'm doing an `strtolower` from the variable and then comparing it with the array.

The problem comes here, when I do `strtolower` on the var with a special character like this one `ø` from `søndag` and `lørdag`, it doesn't recognize the string. How can I change the string to `strtolower` without modifying the special character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [mb_strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php)

```
$weekdays = array("Mandag" => 1, "Tirsdag" => 2, "Onsdag" => 3, "Torsdag" => 4, "Fredag" => 5, "Lørdag" => 6, "Søndag" => 7);

$weekdays = array_combine(
    array_map('mb_strtolower', array_keys($weekdays)),
    $weekdays
);

var_dump($weekdays);
```

Comment: works great for me if I use mb_strtolower($str, 'UTF-8'); thanks!

Comment: @CristianGonzalez: Note that you can also set the default encoding for mb_ functions once and for all using [`mb_internal_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php). This way you don't have to put the second parameter with `mb_strtolower`.

Answer (score 3):

...or if you want to check a specific item in the array you can simply run mb_strtolower($item, 'UTF-8') on it.

```
$happyDay = "SøndAg";
echo $happyDay . ' -> ' . mb_strtolower($happyDay, 'UTF-8');
```